# Using i386 boost on 64 bit machine

Tags: c++, macos, boost, 32bit-64bit

I hope this isn't a duplicate but a bunch of searches haven't been able to help me.

First of all, I am running Mac OS X 10.9.4 (Mavericks) which is unfortunately 64 bit only. I've been tasked with porting some 32 bit code over to this computer (used to work on OS X 10.6.8), but it has been a real hassle. The 32 bit code is poorly written (heavily centered around 32 bit memory allocation) and I don't really have time to go fix all the errors (let alone find them). No, I did not write this code, someone else from my group did several years ago (and he is gone). Necessary are the boost libraries.

As a thought for a solution I thought I might be able to compile the program in 32 bit mode. I'm using Code::Blocks as an IDE if that matters, and gcc 4.4.

I've installed boost libraries (v 1.44) as 32 bit by using

```
sudo ./bjam cxxflags="-m32"
```

when installing. The little test program I am using is from the boost website:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    boost::regex pat( "^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)" );

    while (std::cin)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        boost::smatch matches;
        if (boost::regex_match(line, matches, pat))
            std::cout << matches[2] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I try to compile (with -m32 flag), a warning pops up saying that the library in

```
/usr/local/boost_1_44_0/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a
```

was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64). Similar warning for the main.o file.

So I'm wondering, how can I get this code to compile on a 64 bit computer?

Thanks

Comment: look at related questions, it's there

Comment: Build boost as follows: `./bjam address-model=32`

Comment: @ IgorR. I'll try the address-model flag again (I've tried before), but I know boost is built properly with what I've used. Plus that still doesn't help with the fact that the main.o file won't link to the x86_64 architecture does it?

Comment: You should also pass `-m32` to the linker. Besides, make sure you have 32bit version of `libstdc++`.

Comment: Thanks Igor. I got it all figured out.